# Spring Data Initialization issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot application. I have a configuration service application which provides all configurations for my application. I created a client which pulls all settings for the application and puts them into the context.
I created java class which does this job:

```
@Configuration
public class ContextConfiguration {

    @PostConstruct
    public void getContextConfiguration(){
        ConfigServiceResponse configurations = configurationServiceClient.getConfigurations(configurationEnv);
        Properties properties = generateProperties(configurations.getConfigParameterList());

        MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();

        propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("APPLICATION_PROPERTIES", properties));
    }
 }
```

Also I created java class for configuration of DataSource:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistentConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String serverDbURL;

    @Value("${db.user}")
    private String serverDbUser;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String serverDbPassword;


    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new SingleConnectionDataSource(serverDbURL, serverDbUser, serverDbPassword, true);
    }
}
```

With this configuration the App worked well. Until I migrated to Spring Data. I just added dependency to the Gradle configuration:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

After I added dependency, I can see an exception while the app is starting:

> Error creating bean with name 'persistentConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'db.url' in value "${db.url}

If I remove dependency the App starts with no issues.

And the previous class which configures client and calls it to get data even was not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let Spring know it should process your `ContextConfiguration` first, add a [`DependsOn` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) to the `PersistentConfiguration` like so:

```
@DependsOn("contextConfiguration")
@Configuration 
public class PersistentConfiguration {
    ...
```

The problem is that nothing in your `PersistentConfiguration` tells Spring that it depends on the `ContextConfiguration`, although it does because the former uses variables only initialized by the latter.

This is exactly what `DependsOn` is for. From the JavaDoc:

> Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.